# How to code separate data for a regression parameter in nonlinear regression?

Tags: spss, nonlinear-regression, asymptotics

Say I have a bunch of measurements over a range of my independent variable (example data at the end) and I want to fit them to an equation such as a classic pharmacological inhibition curve:

$Y=B+\frac{M-B}{1+\exp{\left( \ln{X} - \ln{IC_{50}}\right)}}$

I cannot natively use data with $X=0$ in determining the parameters with NLR as $\ln{0}$ is not defined, but theoretically as $X\rightarrow 0$, $Y\rightarrow M$.

Experimentally, it's often easier to combine a negative control and a "baseline" into one treatment by having an untreated group. How can I use this untreated group in determining $M$ in a single NLR analysis? I specifically use SPSS, but any advice with a more theoretical explanation is fine.

Note 1: I know I can just substitute an arbitrarily small value for $X=0$, such as $X=10^{-20}$, but this seems a little... cheaty. Also, I feel like my definition of "arbitrarily small" could affect the regression outcome, especially if weighted regression is involved. Is there a less arbitrary way?

Note 2: If it makes it easier, this doesn't need to be about NLR but instead can be about any asymptotic independent link function in GLM.

EDIT: Maybe I chose a bad example. Here's another one:

$B+\frac{M-B}{1+\exp{\left(H\left( \ln{X} - \ln{IC_{50}} \right) \right)}}$

which is not readily simplified. The equation doesn't matter- what I want to know is this:

Can I specify some data to be used in determining one parameter while other data is used to find other parameters, all while including the uncertainty contained in all measurements in my final model fit?

Edit 2: so far everyone is fixated on the example equations, which really aren't important for my question. For the pedants out there, consider this equation that I am making up:

$A+\frac{B}{1+C\left( \ln{\left( X \right)} - D \right)}$

---

Here's an example dataset:

```
X   Y
0   0.9732462
0   0.9857081
0   1.00479
0.001   0.9811251
0.001   0.982346
0.001   1.028089
0.003   0.9731305
0.003   0.9784695
0.003   0.9815493
0.009   0.9254836
0.009   0.9342329
0.009   0.9448794
0.027   0.8100319
0.027   0.7948713
0.027   0.7979656
0.081   0.5945458
0.081   0.5938009
0.081   0.6131012
0.243   0.3620556
0.243   0.3847672
0.243   0.3633385
0.729   0.2013999
0.729   0.1919975
0.729   0.2240313
2.187   0.1351639
2.187   0.1432508
2.187   0.1508913
```

Comment: What's the matter with rewriting $\exp{( \ln{X} - \ln{IC_{50}})}$ as $X \exp{\left(- \ln{IC_{50}}\right)}$? All your numerical difficulties vanish.

Comment: Can you not algebraically simplify your function? To: $Y=\frac{IC_{50}M + BX}{IC_{50} + X}$

Comment: I used that equation because I'm familiar with it, not because it's a specific equation giving me trouble. I've updated my question with a less convenient example.

Comment: That example is still readily simplified in a way that doesn't require $\ln0$: $Y = B + \frac{(M-B)}{1+(X/IC_{50})^H}$.

Comment: Alright you got me, I was rushing to think of an example between lab work and got sloppy... pretend I had an example on hand that didn't simplify. I'm asking about a theoretical statistical method, not about a specific equation.